# Prove there are no sets $A,B,C$ such that $ A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, $\ A \cap C = \emptyset$, $\ (A \cap B) - C = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Question:

Prove there are no sets $A,B,C$ such that $ A \cap B \neq  \emptyset$, $\  A \cap C = \emptyset$, $\  (A \cap B) - C = \emptyset$

I am not sure how to prove this. I think we need to use proof by contradiction but I am not sure how to show a contradiction.

Comment: @sigmabe In your example, $(A \cap B) - C = \{2\}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael oh sorry...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$ but $x \notin A \cap C$ so $x \notin C$.  Therefore $x \in (A \cap B) - C$, and the latter is not empty.

Comment: How can you conclude that $x \notin A \cap C$?

Comment: because $A∩C=\varnothing$

Answer (score 1):

$A\cap B-C=\varnothing\iff A\cap B\subset C; \quad \forall x\in A\cap B\implies \begin{array}lx\in A\\x\in B\\x\in C \end{array}\implies x\in A\cap C$

Contradiction because $A\cap C=\varnothing$

Answer (score 1):

$A\cap C=\emptyset \implies  (A\cap B )-C= A\cap B $ since $A\cap B \subset A $.  But  $A\cap B \neq \emptyset  $.